Error Deploying Solana Nodes on OVH Machines: QUIC Connection Timed Out
I've been deploying 2 solana nodes (1 RPC and 1 Validator) on OVH machines, but I've encountered the following error:
    2024-05-14T11:06:39.244108182Z WARN  solana_perf] CUDA is disabled [2024-05-14T11:06:39.405284735Z WARN  solana_core::validator] authorized voter: 944J56TN1kS13hWsCk7i4fcWMjGy2DSWxPghMUZACKbD [2024-05-14T11:06:59.597116253Z WARN  solana_quic_client::nonblocking::quic_client] Failed to send data async to 10.20.30.167:8009, error: Custom("ConnectionError(TimedOut)")  [2024-05-14T11:06:59.597251323Z WARN  solana_core::warm_quic_cache_service] Failed to warmup QUIC connection to the leader 944J56TN1kS13hWsCk7i4fcWMjGy2DSWxPghMUZACKbD, Error Custom("\"ConnectionError(TimedOut)\"")
All the ports used in the port range are open in both servers (validator and rpc) and the config in the RPC node is:
    --snapshot-interval-slots 1000  --full-rpc-api  --allow-private-addr  --no-incremental-snapshots  --no-wait-for-vote-to-start-leader  --tpu-use-quic  --tpu-enable-udp  --rpc-port 8899  --dynamic-port-range 8000-8020  --identity /opt/validator-config/bootstrap-validator/identity.json  --accounts /opt/validator-config/bootstrap-validator/ledger/accounts  --ledger /opt/validator-config/bootstrap-validator/ledger  --log /opt/logs/solana-validator.log  --limit-ledger-size 50000000  --vote-account /opt/validator-config/bootstrap-validator/vote-account.json  --gossip-host 10.20.30.166  --gossip-port 8001
Does anyone know why I'm getting this error?
Best regards
I´m trying to send transactions using quic protocol
